# How to create a connection to the 2 Mysql servers?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm totally noob! I have automative test framework previously written for single Mysql server with 2 database on it. And DB connection was looked like

```
public static Connection getConnection() {
    if (conn == null) {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://"
                    + PropertyHandler.getInstance().getValue(PropertyKeys.dbHost)
                    + ":"
                    + PropertyHandler.getInstance().getValue(PropertyKeys.dbPort),
                    PropertyHandler.getInstance().getValue(PropertyKeys.dbUser),
                    PropertyHandler.getInstance().getValue(PropertyKeys.dbPass));
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return conn;
}

public static void closeConnection() {
    try {
        if (conn != null && !conn.isClosed()) {
            conn.close();
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But now they are on different IPs . Please provide simple example how to fix it. Thanks.

Comment: can you please clarify your question? at the moment it is really unclear what `other IPs` mean here. thanks!

Comment: It was like 0.0.0.0  testdb_core and testdb_mail on it . now looks like 0.0.0.0  testdb_core  and 1.1.1.1 testdb_mail   I have query for both DB.  Is it clearly now?

Answer (score 0):

Java DB connection is just a Object. you can create 2 connection Objects for 2 Mysql Servers.

you have getConnection() method created. so you just need to change the method to accept connection parameters.

for example:

```
Connection  db1 = getConnection(server_ip, db, username, password);
Connection  db2 = getConnection(server_ip2, db, username2, password2);
public static Connection getConnection(String ip, String db, String user, String pass) { 
Connection conn = null;
    try {
         Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
         conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://"+ip+"/"+db+"?" +
                               "user="+user+"&password="+pass);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
    return conn;
}
```

Comment: Is this  example correct for 2 connections in the same time. Need to execute query  joined from both DB . As i understend from your example  here getConnection("jdbc:mysql://"+ip+"/"+db+"?" +
                               "user="+user+"&password="+pass); you set parametrs  for db1. Where I should set params for db2 ? just create similar?